# Timelapse won't stop, switches interval and continue while quiting

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first time trying programming, so it's all quite new to me, but I'm having a lot of fun with it.

I have been trying many different things and did a lot of trial and error but can't get past this problem. I'm making a Timelapse camera with GUI for a company as an internship project. As of right now, I've managed to update the interval button through an entry with a button. However, when I press stop, the interval switches from the given time to 1 sec, and keeps on taking pictures. even when pressing stop multiple times, it won't break the thread. After pressing quit, with the root.destroy, it will keep going on as well. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding switching a few lines, tried some google searches, but my knowledge of python is not sufficient enough to understand any of the solutions I could find that would closely resemble my project or situation.

```
class Capture:
    def __init__(self, waittime=30):
        self.capture_stop = False
        self.capture_waittime = waittime
        self.thread = None
        self.capture_running = False

    def capture_worker(self):
        self.capture_running = True

        try:
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (1024, 768)

                for filename in camera.capture_continuous('/home/pi/Time-lapse/project 1 -{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.jpg'):
                    i = 0
                    while i < self.capture_waittime:
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                        i += 0.1
                        if self.capture_stop:
                            break
        finally:
            self.capture_running = False
            self.capture_stop = False

    def start(self):
        if not self.capture_running:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.capture_worker)
            self.capture_stop = False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.capture_running:
            self.capture_stop = True

    def isRunning(self):
        return self.capture_running

    def setWaitTime(self, waittime):
        self.capture_waittime = waittime


capture = Capture()


def startButton():
    interval = float(var_2.get())
    capture.setWaitTime(interval)
    capture.start()


def stopButton():
    capture.stop()


def setInterval():
    global root
    var_1.set("The current interval has been set to: " + var_2.get())
    interval = float(var_2.get())
    capture.setWaitTime(interval)


def quit():
    global root
    capture.stop()
    root.destroy()
```

I expect that when pressed stop, the thread stops and won't update the interval to 1 sec.

Comment: Try change `if self.capture_stop:  break` to `if self.capture_stop:  return`

Comment: How many files do you have? You make time update for each file and _capture_stop_ is check later.

Comment: @HenryYik, That actually solved it! thank you, but could you maybe explain to me why? I wish to understand.

Comment: @AntoJurković, What do you mean?

Comment: Since you are only looking to stop the camera, you can use `return` to safely return from your thread. `break` only breaks out from your `while` loop, but your `for` loop is still running.